# Is there a way to capture the return status of a process without waiting for it?

Tags: c, process, fork, status

What I'm trying to do is have a child process run in the background while the parent goes and does something else.  When the child returns, I'd like for the parent to get that status and do something with it.  However, I don't want to explicitly wait for the child at any point.

I looked into the WNOHANG option of waitpid but this seems to be a little different than what I'm looking for.  WNOHANG just only gets the status if it's done, otherwise it moves on.  Ideally, I'd like some option that will not wait for the process, but will jump back and grab the return status when it's done.

Is there any way to do this?

Code example:

```
pid_t p = fork();
if (p == 0){
    value = do_child_stuff();
    return(value);
}

if (p > 0){
    captureStatus(p, &status); //NOT A REAL FUNCTION
                               // captureStatus will put p's exit status in status
                               // whenever p returns, without waiting or pausing for p 
    //do other stuff.....
}
```

Is there any way to simulate the behavior of captureStatus?

Comment: You can launch in a separate thread and than use some kind of *parallel programming magic* to get result when you need :)

Comment: What use is `captureStatus(p, &status)` if you won't know when `status` will have a valid value?

Comment: Yes, I'm now coming around to Dmitri's view - if you're going to check `status` every so often, why not just use non-blocking `waitpid` at those times?

Comment: @dmitri I realize it's a sort of strange thing to do.  It involves a program where multiple commands are running at the same time and others have dependencies on each other.  At the point one of the dependencies has finished executing, the command that was dependent on it will start executing.  Basically, I'm constantly polling and when that status has a valid value, I run another command.

Comment: The thing is, you won't be able to rely on `status` until you know the process *has exited* and `status` has been set.  So if you're polling it, you may as well use a non-blocking `waitpid()` -- otherwise you'll still need some *other* way of indicating when `status` has a valid value.  How will you know the difference between a garbage value in `status` and the return value from the child process?

Comment: In my program, the status is another variable which I'm initializing to -1.  It's hard to explain exactly how this program works in a comment.  It's true that I could have kept polling waitpid until I got a valid value, and then done something with the return status.  I chose to use a signal handler though because it fit better in my design.  Both approaches would have worked in my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could establish a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` and `wait` for the process once that triggers (it will trigger when the child terminates or is killed).

However, be aware that very few useful things can be done in a signal handler. Everything must be async-signal-safe. [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) specifically mentions `wait` and `waitpid` as safe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the proper way (or at least one proper way) to create an asynchronous wait out of a synchronous one:

```
struct waitpid_async_args {
    pid_t pid;
    int *status;
    int flags;
    sem_t sem, *done;
    int *err;
};

static void *waitpid_async_start(void *arg)
{
    struct waitpid_async_args *a = arg;
    pid_t pid = a->pid;
    int *status = a->status, flags = a->flags, *err = a->err;
    sem_post(&a->sem);
    if (waitpid(pid, status, flags) < 0) *err = errno;
    else *err = 0;
    sem_post(a->done);
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    return 0;
}

int waitpid_async(pid_t pid, int *status, int flags, sem_t *done, int *err)
{
    struct waitpid_async_args a = { .pid = pid, .status = status,
        .flags = flags, .done = done, .err = err };
    sigset_t set;
    pthread_t th;
    int ret;
    sem_init(&a.sem, 0, 0);
    sigfillset(&set);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, &set);
    ret = pthread_create(&th, 0, waidpid_async_start, &a);
    if (!ret) sem_wait(&a.sem);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, 0);
    return ret;
}
```

Note that the asynchronous function takes as an extra argument a semaphore it will post to flag that it's done. You could just examine `status`, but without a synchronization object there's no formal guarantee of memory ordering, so it's better to use an approach like this and call `sem_trywait` or `sem_timedwait` with a timeout to check whether the status is available yet before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can used shared memory IPC functions like `shmget` and `shmat` to communicate between the two processes.  This can be non-blocking and may work well for producer/consumer models like the one you are describing.  You still will have to poll, though.

`shmget` should be called before the fork to create the shared memory block.
Then you can use `shmat` after the fork to get a pointer to the shared memory and just use it as a buffer from there on.
When finished call `shmdt` on both child and parent to detach, and `shmctl` to remove the shared memory.

There is an example on the web [here](http://navet.ics.hawaii.edu/~casanova/courses/ics332_spring12/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I like Vyktor's solution - in the parent process, start a thread to block on the child process and set the `status` variable when it's done.  Here is an implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct return_monitor {
  pid_t pid;
  int *return_status;
};

static void
captureStatus(struct return_monitor *monitor)
{
  printf("Monitor thread started...\n");
  int return_status;
  waitpid(monitor->pid, &return_status, 0);
  *(monitor->return_status) = WEXITSTATUS(return_status);
}

int
main()
{
  printf("Parent process started...\n");
  pid_t p = fork();
  if (p == 0){
    /* child */
    printf("Child process started...\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      sleep(1);
      printf("Child iteration %d...\n", i);
    }
    /* arbitrary return value that will be recognizable in parent */
    return(3);
  }

  if (p > 0){
    int child_return_status = -1;

    struct return_monitor monitor = {p, &child_return_status};
    pthread_t monitor_thread;
    pthread_create(&monitor_thread, NULL, captureStatus, &monitor);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      sleep(2);
      printf("Parent process iteration %d (Child return status %d)...\n",
         i, child_return_status);
    }
    /*     captureStatus(p, &status); */
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach, but your implementation has a number of issues. See my answer.